# Can't confirm new account when joining another site

Tags: bug, login, user-accounts, 500-server-error

I'm trying to have my sockpuppet join a new site, but whatever browser I use (in a private window, so cookies won't matter), I'm greeted with "Oops! Something Bad Happened!". It does not matter if I'm already logged in to another site or not. It happens right after I click 'Confirm new account' here:

[image]

Then I get redirected to this page:

[image]

Comment: Do you use a VPN or something like that? I had the same problem recently and I had to switch my IP address before I was able to join a new community.

Comment: No, but I *am* on a train from the Netherlands to Austria, currently in Germany, so my IP address is definitely different from what it usually is.

Comment: And using a VPN on my home server (just tried) does not work either.

Comment: mmm, then either a different problem with the same error or it was just a coincidence that it worked again once I changed my IP (have a good journey!)

Comment: 0 reputation???? How can that happen?

Comment: @user21339349 is correct, something is very odd with that account, and that's likely the reason why it can't login. Since ordinary users probably can't create such account with 0 rep, the bug affects only mods who use such sock accounts. (no idea how you created it.)

Comment: Reputation is an integer value, and I suspect it shows 0 in absence of any user account. There's nothing special about this sock, it may even been from before my first diamond ...